# MySQL data transfer with re-formatting

Tags: mysql

I have this table synonym_temp:

```
id     | synonyms
----------------------------
1      | ebay,online,dragon
2      | auto, med
```

And I want to transfer it to synonym table but each synonym should be inserted separately. Like:

```
id     | synonym
----------------------------
1      | ebay
1      | online
1      | dragon
2      | auto
2      | med
```

How should I do that? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use PHP

```
$records=mysql_query("select * from synonm_temp");

foreach($records as $row)
{
    $synonums=$row['synonyms'];
    $synonums_array=explode(',', $synonums);
    $id=$row['id'];
    foreach($synonums_array as $syn)
    {
      mysql_query("insert into synonm_temp values ($id,'$syn') ");
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do this with a Numbers or Tally table which contains a sequential list of integers:

```
Select T.id, Substring(T.synonym, N.Value, Locate(', ', T.synonym+ ', ', N.Value) - N.Value)
From Numbers As N
    Cross Join MyTable As T
Where N.Value <= Len(T.synonym)
    And Substring(', ' + T.synonym, N.Value, 1) = ', '
```

In the above case, my `Numbers` table is structured like so:

```
Create Table Numbers( Value int not null primary key )
```